# Comparing two DataTables to determine if it is modified

Tags: c#

I have two DataTables:

`DataTable original;`
`DataTable modified;`

The two tables has the same number of rows and their columns and datas is the same.

I want my `modified` datable to determine each row to compare to the `original` datatable . If a row from the `modified` datatable is not equal to the row of `original` datatable then the row's `.RowState` will be set to `.SetModified()` from the `modified` datatable.

For Example:

...................................................

if row1 in `orginal` is not equal to row1 in `modified` then `row1.SetModified()`

if row2 in `orginal` is not equal to row2 in `modified` `then row2.SetModified()`....etc

............................................................

it should not be like this:

............................................................

if row1 in `orginal` is not equal to row2 in `modified` then `row1.SetModified()`

if row2 in `orginal` is not equal to row3 in `modified` then `row1.SetModified()`...etc

............................................................

get the idea? :)

Any code suggestion without using `Primary Keys`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using foreach loop within another foreach is N X N comparison, that you don't need to do.

Comparing First row with First row of other table, second with second and so on using Zip extension method is very useful for this case.

```
DataTable original;
DataTable modified;

// your stuff

modified = modified.AsEnumerable().Zip<DataRow, DataRow, DataRow>(original.AsEnumerable(), (DataRow modif, DataRow orig) =>
{
    if (!orig.ItemArray.SequenceEqual<object>(modif.ItemArray))
    {
        modif.SetModified();
    }
    return modif;
}).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: This is a great way of doing it. so much less coding

Comment: ok.. this is the most direct to the point answer, thank you very much :)

Comment: just be sure to do some validation on row counts, in case of 0 rows, an System.InvalidOperationException (The source contains no DataRows) is raised.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this code. You can play around with it to see if it will fit your needs:

```
class Program
{
    static void CompareRows(DataTable table1, DataTable table2)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row2 in table2.Rows)
            {
                var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
                var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

                if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Equal: {0} {1}",
                    row1["Drug"], row2["Drug"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not equal: {0} {1}",
                    row1["Drug"], row2["Drug"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static DataTable GetTable1()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David");
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Cecil");
        return table;
     }

     static DataTable GetTable2()
     {
         DataTable table = new DataTable();
         table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
         table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
         table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));

         table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet");
         table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Cecil");
         table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff");
         return table;
     }

     static void Main()
     {
         CompareRows(GetTable1(), GetTable2());
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks I'll try this... I'll comment here if it worked

Comment: is the logic from your code like this?

`if m_row[0] == o_row[0], m_row[1] == o_row[1], m_row[2] == o_row[2]`

and not like this?

`if m_row[0] == o_row[1], m_row[0] == o_row[2], m_row[0] == o_row[3]`

Comment: this array1.SequenceEqual(array2) will do your comparison and inside the if you must set that property value

Comment: Glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in original.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row2 in modified.Rows)
        {
            var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
            var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

            if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
            {
              // Your logic
            }
            else
            {
              // Your logic
            }
        }
    }
```

[**Reference**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-compare-rows)

Comment: thanks I'll try this... I'll comment here if it worked

Comment: is the logic from your code like this?

`if m_row[0] == o_row[0], m_row[1] == o_row[1], m_row[2] == o_row[2]`

and not like this?

`if m_row[0] == o_row[1], m_row[0] == o_row[2], m_row[0] == o_row[3]`

Comment: thanks it worked !!! but i did some changes for the logic :)
but anyway Thank you!!

Comment: I guess i cant accept two answers.. you and @G-Man answered the same right answer at the very same time... but there both useful and helpful.. i dont know which one should I accept

Answer (score 1):

I think following logic is better.

```
static void CompareRows(DataTable original, DataTable modified)
{
    foreach (DataRow row1 in modified.Rows)
    {
        bool isModified = true;
        var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
        foreach (DataRow row2 in original.Rows)
        {
            var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

            if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
            {
                isModified = false;
            }
        }
        if (isModified)
            row1.SetModified();
    }
}
```